# @reboot cronjob not executing

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a Python script which simply writes some text and saves it to a file

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
def main():
     filename = '/home/user/testHello.txt'
     openfile = open(filename,"w")
     print("Hello CRON", file = openfile)
if __name__ == "__main__":
     main();
```

I want to execute this script at startup via CRON.  So I edit the crontab listing by using

```
>crontab -e
```

My entire crontab looks like :

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
PATH = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO = root
HOME = /
# run-parts
1 * * * * /home/user/tester.py
@reboot /home/user/tester.py
```

This is the location of the file, and the file has permissions to execute.  I can run the file no problem as a script from the commandline.  Yet when I restart the machine, no file is generated.  I am trying to understand why, and played around with the crontab entry.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/tester.py
```

This didn't work either.

Edit:

```
ps aux | grep crond
```

gives me

```
user     2259 0.0 0.0.  9436  948 pts/0 S+ 23:39   0:00 grep --color=auto crond
```

I am unsure how to check if crond is running, or if the user in question is mounted before/after CRON.  I'll try with:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

but that hasn't worked either.

Running:

```
pgrep cron
```

returns 957

Comment: 1) check if  crond running at boot? and 2) check to see if /home/user is mounted at time when crond executes  3) your version of crond may not support @reboot are you using vix's crond? ... show results of crontab -l -u user

Comment: @inquisitor What? Nobody wants to trigger a reboot. It is about executing a command AFTER a reboot...

Comment: Borrowing from this page : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-check-cronjob-is-running-not/

It appears crond or its logs aren't active.. Be advised I'm using Lubuntu and chkconfig is not loaded.

Comment: It might be a good idea to set it up as an init script instead of relying on a specific version of cron's @reboot.

Comment: @MarkRoberts , I also tried just having it run every 5 minutes .. still nothing happening.

Comment: running >pgrep cron 
returns 957 (The PID I'm guessing)

Comment: Erik, I was suggesting not to use cron at all.  One thing you may want to do is setup MAILTO so that you can see if the cron is failing due to permissions or something.

Comment: @MarkRoberts I see, perhaps you're right but I wanted to learn CRON and it seems this very basic thing is beyond me.  If I get stuck I'll move into just an init script.  I've also setup the MAILTO , but I'm very new and not seeing any output yet.  Wondering if it's configured properly..

Comment: Who is the crontab running under?  Can you execute the script as that person in their home directory?

Comment: @MarkRoberts this is a fresh virtual environment, I can run the program as that user , root, etc.. it works at the command line just fine as 'user' .. just not working on their crontab.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35185/discussion-between-mark-roberts-and-erik)

Comment: @MarkRoberts removed the reboot and modified the 1 * * * *  , to */1 * * * * , problem is solved!  Where do I send the rep pts Mark? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've discovered just now, the `@reboot` syntax seems to depend on what `crontab` you're editing. I found that for the system-level `/etc/cron.d/` folder, entries there must have a user, just like regular time-based crons.

Thus this worked for me, on Ubuntu 14.04, to run the specified command as root on startup:

```
@reboot root /home/vagrant/log.sh
```

Comment: that was exactly a solution for me, put root after @reboot

Answer (score 3):

Mark Roberts pointed out a few things I'd done wrong.

Namely, the spaces here

```
MAIL = root
HOME = /
```

Get rid of those spaces..

Next, having Cron configuration fixed to email every minute.. instead of what I had :

```
*/1 * * * * /home/user/tester.py
```

Seems to me Lubuntu doesn't support the @Reboot Cron syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem with a `@reboot` cron job not running; in case it helps anyone else:

The problem for me is that my home directory is encrypted with eCryptfs (which is what you get if you choose to encrypt your home directory when installing Ubuntu) - broadly speaking this means that the contents of your home directory aren't available until you log in, but cron runs `@reboot` jobs on reboot, not when you log in.

Comment: How do you know if your home is encrypted? lets say if you were not the one that setup the server. I still cant get @reboot to work on my ubuntu 16

Comment: @Oluwatumbi I can tell by typing `mount | grep home` - I see a line beginning: `/home/.ecryptfs/myaccount/.Private on /home/myaccount type ecryptfs`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get @reboot working with the answer @halfer provided, but want to add an interesting abstract from `man 5 crontab`

> ...
>   The format of a cron command is very much the V7 standard, with a
>   number of upward-compatible extensions.   Each  line  has  five  time 
>   and  date
>          fields,  followed  by  a command, followed by a newline character ('\n').  The system crontab (/etc/crontab) uses the same
>   format, except that the
>          username for the command is specified after the time and date fields and before the command. The fields may be separated by spaces 
>   or  tabs.  The
>          maximum permitted length for the command field is 998 characters.
>   ...

So you might check these as well in case the job is still not running.