# Running Script at boot using Cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron, startup, odroid

I want to execute a script once my computer boots up with cron.
But it doesn't work.

My OS is Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS.

My crontab 
[image]

My script
[image]

My script's absolute path 
[image]

**Once my Odroid boots up, the keyboard is still in qwerty.**
What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:**
I tried `@reboot echo "hi" > /home/valery/reboot.txt 2>&1`
It works so the issue is not in the @reboot job.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**
I run my script from System > Preference > Personal > Startup Applications
It's working fine.

Comment: Please include your crontab and script in your question as code, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

The `setxkbmap` command depends on the `$DISPLAY` environment variable to specify the X display it will affect.

On my system, if I run it without setting `$DISPLAY`, I get:

```
$ setxkbmap fr
Cannot open display "default display"
```

Crontab does not set `$DISPLAY` for the jobs it runs. In fact it provides only a minimal set of environment variables (on my system, just `$HOME`, `$LOGNAME`, `$PATH`, `$LANG`, `$SHELL`, and `$PWD`).

Anything a command prints to `stdout` or `stderr` will normally be e-mailed to the owner of the crontab. You're likely to have an e-mail message on your system containing an error message similar to the above.

It's likely that X Windows isn't even running yet when crontab executes the `@reboot` job. You'll have to find another way to run that command automatically, or just run it manually. (Or there could be another way to do this that I haven't thought of.)

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, and the solution that worked was to put the following into "Startup Applications": `bash -c "xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY"`. (It didn't work without wrapping it into the `bash -c "..."` and I'm not sure exactly why.) By the way, "Startup Applications" seems to be simply creating a `YOUR_COMMAND_NAME.desktop` file under `~/.config/autostart`.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: That doesn't use cron -- but of course if it works, it works. My guess is that the `bash -c` was needed so that `$HOME` and `~` could be expanded. (Probably cleaner to use `$HOME` consistently.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [systemd/upstart job for this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal)?

PS:

#### Example

Try this example. If it wouldn't work then try to find a bug

*Replace `/home/valery/` with a path to your home folder:*

```
$ crontab -l
@reboot echo "hi" > /home/valery/reboot.txt 2>&1
```

I then rebooted the system.

```
$ sudo reboot
```

After the reboot.

```
$ cat reboot.txt 
hi
```

#### Bugs

1. [cron: @reboot jobs are not run](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=635473).
2. The bug in Ubuntu would seem to be confirmed here in this SO Q&A titled: [@reboot cronjob not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158427/reboot-cronjob-not-executing).

Someone was attempting the very same thing and getting frustrated that it didn't work. It's titled: [Thread: Cron - @reboot jobs not working](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1530652).

Comment: I tried your example: It works. I edited my post so that others can see your example works.